# "Discriminant Coordinates" and "Latent Variables" -- translations for a Peruvian audience

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, matemáticas, perú

I need to verify my translation of 2 related statistical terms into Spanish, for presentation to an audience in Peru.

Sadly, the largest list of "Mathematics and Statistics" Spanish-English translations I found did not have these listed.

The terms are:

1. **Discriminant Coordinants**
2. **Latent Variables**

In English, these are defined as follows:

1. [Discriminate Coordinates](http://datamining.togaware.com/survivor/Discriminant_Coordinates0.html) --  a plot of the primary differences between clusters (in Discriminate Analysis, which is a subset of Cluster Analysis), and which, being based on latent variables and eigenvalues, is similar to Principal Components Analysis
2. [Latent Variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_variable) -- variables that are not directly observed but are rather inferred (through a mathematical model) from other variables that are observed

My best-guess translation for these are:

1. **Coordenadas Discriminantes**
2. **Variable Latente**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the link to wikipedia you provided and switching language to Spanish, it seems that `Latent Variable` is indeed translated as ["Variable latente"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_latente).

"Coordenadas Discriminantes" seems to be a proper translation for `Discriminate Coordinates`. Maybe there is no term in Spanish to refer to the kind of plot you link on your question, but that translation will be suitable for your audience, since they will have a good knowledge of the domain (data mining, computer science, maths, etc.) and will probably be familiar with the original term in English too.

Answer (score 3):

About the second term, I'm sure it is *Variable latente*.
You can check it in both english ans spanish versions on wikipedia:
[Latent variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_variable)
[Variable Latente](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_latente)

About the first term, I guess it is *Variables Discriminantes* (if these are the same as "predictor variables" in english), based in Latent Variables (Variables Latentes) and Eigenvalues (Autovectores o Valores Propios).

Comment: Muchas gracias, +1